# Bash Script to Monitor CPU clock speed

Tags: bash, cpu

I made a simple program but it prints all CPU speeds on ONE line... Any suggestions how to make each CPU print on its own line?

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]
    do 
        my_array=( $(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz) )
        printf '%s\033[A\n%s\033[A\n%s\033[A\n%s\033[A\n' "${my_array[*]}"
        sleep 1
    done
```

Comment: Please add your desired output to your question (no comment).

Comment: What's wrong with the `while :; do grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo; echo; sleep 1; done` or `watch grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo` ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPa_08N7wYg --- thanks for input everyone --- heres a short vid of the outputs from each script people gave.

Comment: Are you trying to get your CPU speed to jump up higher than idle by wasting cycles starting a separate `cat` process to pipe to `grep`?

Comment: I am not trying to increase my speed of CPU I am just learning how to code and this was just an idea/problem I had to solve.

Comment: Then use `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo`.  See https://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/useless-use-of-cat/ re: useless use of `cat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]
    do.
        IFS="\n"
        my_array=( $(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz) )
        for item in ${my_array[*]}
         do
          echo ${item}
          sleep 1
          clear
        done
    done
```

Pay attention to the `IFS` variable. `IFS=$'\n'` (newline) is required to interpret each line from the multiline grep output as a new array item.

By default, `IFS` is `[::space::]` or not defined.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: A more robust way to read multiline output into an array would be `readarray`/`mapfile`. Also, the default value of `IFS` is `$' \t\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```bash
watch "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz"
```

Comment: oh I see how to use it, so simple!

Comment: This doesn't need `cat`, just `watch grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo`.  That should waste less CPU time, maybe letting your CPU cores stay at idle clock speed for more of the read from that special file.  An aggressive governor or EPP (energy_performance_preference) setting on a modern CPU (especially Intel with hardware P-state management) can decide to clock itself up in the 10s of microseconds it takes for this to fork+exec grep every second, if it wasn't already clocked high from some work happening.